# What are the consequences of changing my Apple ID password?

Tags: apple-id, facetime

If I change my Apple ID password, will that disconnect or block all devices from accessing my FaceTime through my Apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you change your password you will have to change the password on all your devices in order to have FaceTime working correctly.

The same for iCloud and the other services which are linked to your Apple ID.